# How to use jQuery appendTo() to insert elements before the children

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<div id='1'>
    <div id='2'><div>
</div>
```

If I do:  `$("<img/>").appendTo('#1');`

The result is:

```
   <div id='1'>
            <div id='2'><div><img/>
    </div>
```

How to chage the query so that the result will be?:

```
<div id='1'>
        <img/><div id='2'><div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).  E.g.,

```
$("<img/>").prependTo('#1');
```